# xPage managedBean ODA application error

Tags: java, xpages

Navigating from one page to other constantly get following error.
Error not related with any of my code at least from stack trace.
From debug prints seems that it happen after page is loaded.

Any thoughts?

```
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.openntf.domino.impl.Document
    com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractStateManager.saveSerializedView(AbstractStateManager.java:121)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.StateManagerImpl.saveSerializedView(StateManagerImpl.java:152)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._saveViewState(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:455)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.saveViewState(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:449)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:324)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:336)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:270)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:261)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:588)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:865)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:808)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:577)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.openntf.domino.impl.Document
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    java.util.TreeMap.writeObject(TreeMap.java:5740)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1059)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1502)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1555)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1516)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1555)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1516)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:942)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1059)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1502)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared(ObjectOutputStream.java:413)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectOutputStream.writeObjectEx(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:438)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectOutputStream.writeObjectEx(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:417)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectOutputStream.writeObjectEx(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:417)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectOutputStream.writeObjectEx(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:417)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager$FastObjectOutputStream.writeObjectEx(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:417)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager.saveSerializedView(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:294)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractSerializingStateManager.doSaveSerializedView(AbstractSerializingStateManager.java:269)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.FileStateManager.doSaveSerializedView(FileStateManager.java:290)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.FileStateManager.doSaveSerializedView(FileStateManager.java:270)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.AbstractStateManager.saveSerializedView(AbstractStateManager.java:114)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.StateManagerImpl.saveSerializedView(StateManagerImpl.java:152)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._saveViewState(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:455)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.saveViewState(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:449)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:324)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:336)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:270)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:261)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:588)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:865)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:808)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:577)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store any Domino object in a managed bean. As the method says, it's not serializable. ODA cannot work around that issue.

My recommendation would be to store either the DominoDocument object (if you need the front-end document, so updating it during the life of the bean but not saving each time) or the UNID (if you just need the backend document). `Database.getDocumentByUNID()` is extremely fast, so you should not be concerned about the performance impacts of getting the document.

If you want to avoid getting the document multiple times in the XPages lifecycle, put the resulting Document object in `requestScope` and check there before retrieving from the database. Alternatively (I'm not sure how best practice this is or if it is properly cleaned up) it may be an option to set the variable to `transient`, so it will not be serialized at the end of each request, but will be held in the bean for the duration of each partial refresh.

Comment: Then check viewScope, sessionScope or applicationScope. The code is definitely trying to serialize a Document object, the stack trace proves that. If it's not in your managed bean, you're trying to store it in a scoped variable.

Comment: Document.docAsMap() could have domino object in it? it is only place I could imagine it hides...

Comment: I found it mysefl already - Document.docAsMap() is still Document

Comment: Correct, it just returns the current object, which can then be queried as a java Map https://stash.openntf.org/projects/ODA/repos/dominoapi/browse/domino/core/src/main/java/org/openntf/domino/impl/Document.java?at=refs%2Fheads%2Fdevelop#4137